# Javascript string object to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I want to pass some data from html to jquery using data-attribute like this:

```
<div data-frames="[
    { src: 'artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' }
]"></div>
```

I don't know a way how could I use this structure in jquery so it keeps the same format (array with objects). Is there a way to do this?

Using string.split(',') doesn't help me here.

Comment: Is that format fixed or is it your own, and can you make slight changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you swap the use of single and double quotes (to make it JSON compliant), the [jQuery `data` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) does the JSON parsing on-the-fly:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). [ ... ]
>
> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string; it must follow [valid JSON syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) *including quoted property names*.

#### Demo:

```js
// jQuery recognises JSON:
console.log($('div').data('frames'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-frames='[
    { "src": "artwork-96.png",  "sizes": "96x96",   "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "artwork-128.png", "sizes": "128x128", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "artwork-192.png", "sizes": "192x192", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "artwork-256.png", "sizes": "256x256", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "artwork-384.png", "sizes": "384x384", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "artwork-512.png", "sizes": "512x512", "type": "image/png" }
]'></div>
```

Comment: precise and perfect answer. didn't know that the `data` attribute does the `JSON` parsing

Comment: would appreciate your inputs on my edited answer below

Answer (score 2):

<s>`JSON.stringify(your_data)` before assigning it to `data-frames`. And while fetching, `JSON.parse(your_data)` before using.</s>

**EDIT:** Since the data is not in the correct `JSON` format, there are two ways of accessing it using javascript.

1. As pointed out by @trincot, put formatted `JSON` to your `data-frames`, and then access it using `.data` method. **Note:** If the data is not in proper `JSON` format (just like it is seen in the question) the 2nd way (point #2 below) will work.
2. Using `eval("("+your_data+")")` will evaluate your data string into a javascript `object`. **You can only then use `JSON` methods on it (i.e. after evaluation)**.

After using both the ways ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/r1sjv2tv/3/) with lots of console logs), I think the 1st one would be a better solution (**as pointed out by @trincot**)

Comment: Instead of suggesting `eval()`, suggest `JSON.parse()` like you did before. It is safer as it only accepts ... JSON (no functions, side-effects...). But now I see you propose it to deal with the non-JSON format. I would not go that way though. `eval` has a bad name.

Comment: yes i found `eval` opens doors to threats but i was struggling to parse the unformatted json string, and the only way i found to parse it was through `eval`uating the string enclosed by parens

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a better tool for storing complex data versus HTML. I'd change your solution so that your element contains a reference to a data structure in your JavaScript instead of the raw data itself:

```js
var data = {
    someUniqueKey: [
        { src: 'artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' }
    ]
};

$('div[data-frames]').each(function(i, el) {
    var key = $(el).data('frames');

    console.log(data[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-frames="someUniqueKey"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is rigid then in pure JS you can do as follows

```js
var datas = document.getElementById("datas");
     data = JSON.parse(datas.dataset.frames.replace(/(\w+):\s*'([\w\:\.\-\\\/]+)'/g, "\"$1\": \"$2\""));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="datas" data-frames="[
    { src: 'artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
    { src: 'artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' } ]"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `parseJSON()` function of jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/